# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PIVOT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have an SQL query that is throwing an error.

```
SELECT aggregationqueueid, organizationid, locationid, businessDate, jobname, starttime,
             completiontime, errorflag, completionstatus, metadata, servername,message,history, aggproperties,
             retrycount, maxretry
             FROM aggregation_queue  where aggregationQueueId in
               (SELECT aggregationQueueId FROM
                 (SELECT * FROM
                  aggregation_queue a
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                 (
                     SELECT organizationId,locationId,jobName,completionStatus FROM aggregation_queue WHERE completionStatus >=1
                     and jobName IN ("DailyDefinitions")
                 )
                 PIVOT
                    ( MAX(jobName)
                      FOR jobName IN (["DailyDefinitions"])
                ) AS b
                on a.organizationId = b.organizationId and a.locationId = b.locationId
                WHERE a.jobName = "DailyDefinitions"  and a.completionStatus is null )temp
                WHERE jobname = "DailyDefinitions" ) 
                ORDER BY aggregationQueueId;
```

Can someone please guide on what is the error in the query.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
> 'PIVOT'.

Answer (score 0):

You must enclose the subquery as follows:

```
...
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                 (
                     SELECT organizationId,locationId,jobName,completionStatus FROM aggregation_queue WHERE completionStatus >=1
                     and jobName IN ("DailyDefinitions")
                 )
                 PIVOT
                    ( MAX(jobName)
                      FOR jobName IN (["DailyDefinitions"])
                )
                  ) AS b
...
...
```